# How to redirect page from view

Tags: python, pyramid

how do I redirect a page from my views.py? Since each view method expects a response, how would I go about returning to the home page as an example (127.0.0.1:1234/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it in the documentation: (of course after I ask , google gives me an answer..(did google beforehand))

```
exc.HTTPFound(request.route_url("home"))
```